# MySql :: use Limit and OrderBy

Tags: mysql, sql

when I try to run this query i get syntax error in last line, this happend after  I add the **Limit** and **orderby** :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_GetFilesInfo`;

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_GetFilesInfo`(pFileID varchar(20),pFileName varchar(100),pExrtention int,pParentID varchar(20),pSize int,pReferenceID int,pIndex int,pNumOfRec int)
BEGIN
SELECT  FileID,
                FileName,
                FilePath,
                Size,
                Exrtention,             
                ParentID,
                IsFolder,
                ModificationDate,               
                filesrefrences.ReferenceID,
                filesrefrences.RefrenceCount,
                filesrefrences.RefrenceKey
from filesinfo LEFT OUTER JOIN filesrefrences ON   (filesrefrences.ReferenceID = filesinfo.ReferenceID)

WHERE       (pFileID=-99 OR pFileID is NULL OR filesinfo.FileID=pFileID)
                AND (pFileName='' OR pFileName is NULL OR filesinfo.FileName LIKE CONCAT('%', pFileName,'%'))
                AND (pExrtention=-99 OR pExrtention is NULL OR filesinfo.Exrtention =pExrtention)
                AND (pParentID=-99 OR pParentID is NULL  OR filesinfo.ParentID=pParentID)               
                AND (filesinfo.ReferenceID= pReferenceID OR pReferenceID=-99 OR pReferenceID is NULL)
                AND (filesinfo.Size=pSize OR pSize=-99 OR pSize is NULL)  ORDER BY IsFolder DESC LIMIT 0;           
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the value of `LIMIT` should be greater than 0 if `duration` (*how many records to display*) is not supplied

```
ORDER BY IsFolder DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

- [Limit - MySQL Command](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

if you have supplied a *duration*, the index of the first record on the result is zero, eg

```
ORDER BY IsFolder DESC 
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

where `0` is the *index* and `1` is the *duration*

Comment: yes, this is logical, but i find  the error is " **DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` **"